# Multiple Observable Arrays

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I'm trying to get some data from my server, create objects from this data, and then display it on my page in a foreach data bind.

Here is my code:

```
self.houses = ko.observableArray([]);
self.flats = ko.observableArray([]);

function Building(item, checked){
    self = this;
    self.id = item.id;
    self.name = item.nazwa;
    self.photo = '/' + item.pic;
    self.type = item.type_text;
    self.selected = ko.observable(checked);
}

$.getJSON("/api/getHouses", function(allData) {
    self.houses($.map(allData, function(item) { return new Building(item, 0) }));
});

$.getJSON("/api/getFlats", function(allData) {
    self.flats($.map(allData, function(item) { return new Building(item, 0) }));
});
```

When i run this code, I get an error:

```
self.flats is not a function
```

If I were to remove one of the getJSON functions, and only have one (either one), it works fine. Can I only have one observableArray at once?

Comment: There's no reason you can't have more than one observableArray. I would guess that there's a scoping issue somewhere. Can you show your full viewmodel?

Comment: @JasonSpake It's quite a lot of code. What do you mean by scoping? It's all in one view model. Is that a problem?

Comment: By scoping I mean the context of "self". If you have more than one self variable it might not be the one you are expecting at the point that error is thrown. Is the ajax call being executed from within a function or is it really in the root viewmodel as you have it above?

Comment: @JasonSpake it's in the root viewmodel. There is only 1 self.

Comment: I see at least one other in your Building function. In fact there's no "var" in front of it there so perhaps it's changing the root's "self" to that of the Building's.

Comment: @JasonSpake That did the trick. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that the "self" variable is being mutated by the Building function and no longer points to the root viewmodel when the ajax call returns. The fix might be as simple as placing "var" in front of `self = this`

```
self.houses = ko.observableArray([]);
self.flats = ko.observableArray([]);

function Building(item, checked){
    //self = this; 
    var self = this; //the fix
    self.id = item.id;
    self.name = item.nazwa;
    self.photo = '/' + item.pic;
    self.type = item.type_text;
    self.selected = ko.observable(checked);
}
```